# Cant put Accept() (CSocket) in its own thread

Tags: c++, sockets

I use blocking server-client to do a FTP homework.
But i got stuck when try to put Accept into a thread. (Everytime i run the CServer , it crahses and shut down)
Anyone know the answer or can suggest me sth else. i really appreciate it.

I really want to use blocking and CSocket ,so dont't suggest me non-blocking
I also took a look at p_thread, but i still won't if any chance my code works

```
void CServerDlg::OnBnClickedListen()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    if (listen.Create(PORT, SOCK_STREAM, _T("127.0.0.1")) == 0) {
        showMessage("Failed to init socket");
        listen.GetLastError();
        return;
    }
    else {
        if (listen.Listen(1) == FALSE) {
            showMessage("Can't listen to the port");
            listen.Close();
            return;
        }

    }
    connectThread = thread(&CServerDlg::ThreadMain, this);

}


void CServerDlg::ThreadMain() {

    int cnt = -1;
    CSocket* client;

    while (1)
    {
        client = new CSocket();

        if (listen.Accept(*client)) // it crashes everytime i got here
        {
            cnt++;
            char * id = Converter::StringToChar(Converter::NumberToString(*client));
            clients.push_back(client);
            ClientId.push_back(id);

            showMessage("Found a connection with client " + Converter::CharToString(id));

            /*
                 Thread here
            */
           threads.push_back(thread(&CServerDlg::ThreadProc, this, cnt));
        }
        else break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate ***"I get stuck"***

Comment: Everytime i run CserverDlg, i Click Listen, but the Dialog suddenly shut down,

Comment: Put a breakpoint, from there single-step

Comment: Could you get me some details. i dont get it

Comment: What environment are you using? Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes visual studio - Windows

Comment: In the part that crashes, put a breakpoint (F9). Run your code (F5). When the breakpoint is hit you continue with single step (F10).